# reshaping data in R skipping certain measured variables

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I would like to reshape a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
     permno         dte ttm var1 var2 var3
1    123  2012-01-01  20    1   10  100
2    123  2012-01-01  30   -1   10  100
3    124  2012-01-01  20    2   20  200
4    124  2012-01-01  30   -2   20  200
```

I would like to make my `data.frame` look the following way:

```
  permno         dte var1_20 var1_30 var2 var3
1    123  2012-01-01       1      -1   10  100
2    124  2012-01-01       2      -2   20  200
```

I have been attempting to do this with `reshape2` package but I am unable to isolate `var1` from the rest and keep getting `var2_20` and `var2_30` for example in the results.  Does anyone know how to do this using the `reshape2` package?

data.frame dput:

```
> dput(DF)
structure(list(permno = c(123L, 123L, 124L, 124L), dte = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = " 2012-01-01", class = "factor"), ttm = c(20L, 
30L, 20L, 30L), var1 = c(1L, -1L, 2L, -2L), var2 = c(10L, 10L, 
20L, 20L), var3 = c(100L, 100L, 200L, 200L)), .Names = c("permno", 
"dte", "ttm", "var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> dput(result)
structure(list(permno = 123:124, dte = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = " 2012-01-01", class = "factor"), 
    var1_20 = 1:2, var1_30 = c(-1L, -2L), var2 = c(10L, 20L), 
    var3 = c(100L, 200L)), .Names = c("permno", "dte", "var1_20", 
"var1_30", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `merge`, `reshape`, and `unique` as follows:

```
unique(merge(DF[-c(3:4)], 
             reshape(DF[1:4], direction = "wide", 
                     idvar = c("permno", "dte"), 
                     timevar="ttm")))
#   permno         dte var2 var3 var1.20 var1.30
# 1    123  2012-01-01   10  100       1      -1
# 3    124  2012-01-01   20  200       2      -2
```

Basically, you reshape only the columns that need to be reshaped, and drop those columns from the original dataset before merging. You'll end up with duplicated rows, so just wrap all of that in `unique` to get (almost) your desired output. You can rearrange the column order if required.

Comment: +1 great solution, this is basically what i'm doing now. i was hoping there would be "prettier" way but thsi might be the way to go if not

Answer (score 2):

I'm feeling rather clever about this answer, but I strongly suspect that I've made too many assumptions about your data, in particular the constant nature of var2 and var3:

```
ddply(dat,.(permno,dte,var2,var3),
      function(x) { dcast(x,permno + dte + var2 + var3 ~ ttm,value.var = 'var1') })
  permno         dte var2 var3 20 30
1    123  2012-01-01   10  100  1 -1
2    124  2012-01-01   20  200  2 -2
```

Comment: I have a similar suspicion about the assumptions--I sort of did the same with my answer, but it's always nice to have alternatives. +1

Comment: +1 i like what you were thinking here. one issue that i do wonder is since var2 and var3 are `numeric` and not `integer` in real data, would this cause an issue (since 123.23 != 123.23 in R right?)

Comment: @Alex If that is a problem (try and see), you could use the alternative formula system: `library(plyr); dcast(df,list(.(permno,dte,round(var2),round(var3)),.(ttm)),value.var="var1")`